# NXT Sensors not working

Tags: nxt, sensor

I'm looking for advice. I pulled my Mindstorms 8547 kit out of storage and started to play with it after several years of inactivity.

I found that the Color Sensor, the Ultra Sonic Sensor, and the position read back on motors all do not function. I downloaded the latest software and firmware version 1.31.

Any idea what is going on? Do I need to go back to a previous firmware version to get things to work as they did originally?

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is there any chance it's simply your code that isn't working? Could you add a screenshot of the program you're using to test the functions?

Comment: Using the "View" directly from the NXT brick to test the sensors, just get all ?????on the display with the color or ultrasonic sensor plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Check for 5V on the two middle pins of the motor connectors (plug a cable into the brick, no motor on the other end,  and measure volatege on the contacts of the open other end). NXT/EV3 have separate power to all the sensors, if there's a short (failed capacitor or similar) or the power chip failed then the brick will still work, but the sensors won't get power.

Answer (score 0):

This honestly just sounds like a faulty cable. See the NXT cable pinout below. If wire 5 or 6 is damaged it will cause digital I2C sensors to fail. This includes the color and ultrasonic sensors, but not the (analog) touch sensors.

Also, according to [this source](http://www.brickengineer.com/pages/2008/09/05/lego-nxt-motor-wiring/), pin 5 and 6 are also used for the motor encoders. So damage to 5 or 6 will cause rotation feedback to fail.

This sounds exactly like the issues you are having. The solution? Try a different cable to confirm that the issue is a faulty wire, then (optionally) buy new cables from [here](http://www.mindsensors.com/51-cables-connectors).

[image: NXT Wire Pinout]